# Why did setting a static IP fix my LAN connection issue?

Tags: networking, router, lan, dhcp

My router is working perfectly, and all other computers use automatic DHCP to get an IP address (all hard wired--no wireless). This one laptop lan connection kept getting stuck "identifying" the network, until I set a static IP in the ipv4 config properties (win7).

Why would that resolve the issue?

Comment: With Windows it's always something. Did you try `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` before you did the static IP? And did you also reboot your DHCP server/router? I've had it where certain devices will connect just fine, while other won't be able to. A reboot of the router always worked and a reboot of the computer never hurt.

Comment: I didn't try any of that because the wi-fi card (which I prefer to keep disabled) was able to connect just fine, so I guess I assumed (bad mission with windows) the lan should be fine too. I thought about rebooting the router/firewall, but I'm kind of proud of the fact that my pfsense home build has not needed a reboot in over a year. Oh well, time to swallow my pride :~(... Thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: Tell me if any of that works!

Comment: Well, I've tried all of the suggestions except wireshark and the only thing that works is setting a static IP on the machine itself. Weird... and good thing I don't care if it has a static IP. Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a group policy using gpedit.msc under Administrative Templates\Network\Network Connections\Windows Firewall\
Prohibit unicast response to multicast or broadcast requests" to Enabled.

Info:
If you disable or do not configure this policy setting and this computer sends a multicast or broadcast message to other computers Windows Firewall waits as long as three seconds for unicast responses from the other computers and then blocks all later responses

But this should not affect DHCP requests, Anyway give it a shot.

Comment: If that did not work, try to disable firewall and try acquiring lease again.

Comment: Found the issue. All the DHCP leases were in use within the small range I had specified. I expanded the range and manually released several old leases that had not timed out yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems DHCP is not working between your laptop and router. Try running wireshark on your laptop to capture the traffic while DHCP is happening.